# Localized HTML caching in CDN

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cdn

I have a localized html page, the field texts of the html page are pulled from blob storage (e.g register-en-US.json file) based on user culture code passed in query string. We are planning to use Azure CDN for better performance, but I am wondering, how CDN will cache this file, as it is more of a dynamic page. 
Anyone has any suggestion around this?

Answer (score 0):

You can define how the CDN treats query string.
Set Query String Caching to 'cache as unique', and it will cache different versions of your html which can pull different localized JSON files.

Comment: You mentioned it is dynamic, but unless its different for every user, your content can still be cached.